# my table doesn't need primary key, should I use one?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have table to check if user with specific ip address rated on an item or not with these columns: `rates(ip,item_id,created_at)` I can define two primary key for this table

1- primary(ip,item_id)

2-  primary(id)

but I really don't need them because **no join** and **no update** needed for this table, should I define primary key?
I can just index item_id and ip for performance but no primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a primary key.  As ctrahey said, if the combinations are to be unique then use option#1, if not use #2 (with the additional column).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `WHERE` clauses in your `SELECTs`.  That's a quick and (very) dirty way to see what needs to be indexed.

You should have `PRIMARY KEY`.  It must be unique.  It can either be a 'natural' key -- if you don't want any duplicate `ip` values, that that is a good candidate.  If you don't have a 'natural' PK, then have an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

You cannot have two `PRIMARY KEYs`, but the one PK can have two columns.

[Cookbook on building indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 1):

In general, design for the future as well as for today. You have a very natural composite primary key, unless you can or ever will be able to rate an item more than once, in which case you should introduce the id column.